# Download all PDF links in a web page?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, download, download-manager

Do you know a good software to download all PDF links in a web page??

Operating system is Windows 7.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) and run a command like this:

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --no-directories --no-host-directories --accept pdf http://example.com
```

Or with the short options:

```
wget -r -l 1 -nd -nH -A pdf http://example.com
```

UPDATE: Since your update says you are running Windows 7: use [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) from a `cmd` prompt.

UPDATE 2: For a graphical solution - though it may be overkill since it gets other files too is [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/)

Comment: thank you kevin for your advice, wget looks good, anyway i would prefer a 'graphic' software, non command line. :)

Comment: This rejects even the initial .html page. Has it ever been tested?

Comment: The question asks about downloading all PDF links, so yes, the initial .html page will be ignored.

Comment: Is there a posibility to do the same thing in Windows 7 using Power Shell?

Comment: I would also suggest throwing in a delay of at least a few seconds between file downloads so as to be nice and not overwhelm the remote server. e,g, for wget, add in a flag of `-w 5`

Answer (score 12):

1. In your browser, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, and enter

   > var pdflinks =[]; Array.prototype.map.
   >   call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href$=\".pdf\"]"), function(e, i){if((pdflinks||[]).indexOf(e.href)==-1){ pdflinks.push( e.href);}  });
   >   console.log(pdflinks.join(" "));

   This will return in the console:

   > "https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/somepdf1.pdf" "https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/somepdf2.pdf" "https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/somepdf3.pdf"
2. Now using [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) with the command line options `wget url1 url2 ...`

Copy and paste this, open a console enter `wget` press the right mouse button to insert your clipboard content and press enter.

To use a download file, join the lines with "\n" and use the parameter as follows `wget -i mydownload.txt`

Note that most other (GUI) download programs too accept to be called with a space separated list of URLs.

Hope this helps. This is how I generally do it. It is faster and more flexible than any extension with a graphical UI, I have to learn and remain familiar with.

Comment: Better yet, `console.log('"' + pdflinks.join('" "') + '"')` -- otherwise you don't actually get quoted URLs

Comment: You can also use `copy(pdflinks.join(" "))` to avoid manually copying the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in the browser, I've written a web extension for exactly this purpose - I'm working on adding the ability to save scholarly article PDFs with properly formatted titles but if you just want to download 'em all it's perfect for this.

It's called *Tab Save* and on the Chrome web store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki). You don't even have to input the list of URLs if you just open them all in tabs (but for large numbers of files this might slow a computer down so I added the option to add your own).

Answer (score 0):

I recently used [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/) (on Windows) for this.  It has a GUI, and you can filter the files you intend to download.

Saves trying to remember all those

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome, it's possible to use extensions such as:

- [Download Master](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-master-free-down/laepcndcehndnjndpfjdcdgbneoimdgg)

  > With this extension you can download all images, videos, pdf, doc and any other file linked on the web page you are visiting.

Answer (score 0):

#### Google

There are few Python tools which allows downloading PDF links from the website based the Google search results.

E.g.

- [`google_dl` script](https://github.com/mycognitive/google_dl) (recommended).

  Usage:

  ```
  ./google_dl -s http://www.example.com/ -f pdf ""
  ```
- [`gsrchDwn` script](https://github.com/kenorb/gsrchDwn) (based on [neo's script](http://web.archive.org/web/20180118184134/https://infosec-neo.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/python-script-to-download-files-via.html)).

  Usage:

  ```
  ./gsrchDwn.py --query "site:http://www.example.com/" --ftype pdf
  ```

<sup>Note: I'm the maintainer of both mentioned scripts.</sup>

Both of them are implementing [`xgoogle`](https://github.com/mycognitive/xgoogle) Python library. My fork of this library is based on the [`pkrumins/xgoogle` version](https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle).

---

Related: [A web search from the Linux command line](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34609/3474).